# Quartz Scheduler keeps creating new objects leading to OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, quartz-scheduler

I've just implemented Quartz following the quick start guide:

```
import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.newJob;
import static org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule;
import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.newTrigger;

import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
import org.quartz.Trigger;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;

public class Quartz {

    public static void startScheduler() throws InterruptedException{

        try {
        Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
        // Grab the Scheduler instance from the Factory
        scheduler.start(); // and start it off

        JobDetail job = newJob(RepetitiveRun.class) 
        // define the job and tie it to RepetitiveRun class
        .requestRecovery()// ask scheduler to re-execute this job
        .withIdentity("job1", "group1")
        .build();

        Trigger trigger = newTrigger() 
         // Trigger the job to run now, and then repeat every x seconds
         .withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
         .startNow()
         .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
         .withIntervalInSeconds(2) 
          // how often should the job repeat (once every x seconds)
         .repeatForever())
          .build();

          scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger); 
          // Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1200000000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } // how many seconds the Main should run

            scheduler.shutdown();

        } catch (SchedulerException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }

        }

}
```

The RepetitiveRun class that implements Job executes queries and writes to files.

The problem is that the heap continuously increases, and after a while java.lang.OutOfMemoryError is thrown.

Using VisualVM I see that the Live Bytes, Live Objects and Generations associated with the RepetitiveRun class are constantly increasing, which suggests that this is the cause for the memory leak.

Is it possible to make Quartz delete/release all objects created during the execution of a job which has already finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally this is a job for the garbage collector (cleaning up after the job is finished).

When the job has finished and no more references are there on the job then the garbage collector should clean up.

I suspect that you either leak your job outside of it (e.g. passing `this` to any other object that stores a reference to your job).

Or you clean not up the resources that have to be cleaned up by you (e.g. database connections or file handles).

This leads to a memory leak that you have to track down with a profiler and clean up what is needed (either by not leaking your object to the outside or closing all resources that you open/create).